# Gantry5 framework - Where are the core particles located?

Tags: menu, layout, gantry

I am trying to customize my Gantry5 Header and Menu. I searching for the menu particle but I can't find in my template.

**Where is the core menu particle located?**

---

Some extra info about what I am trying to do.

I need to have three sections:

1. **A Logo section**
2. **A Main Menu section**
3. **A Sub Menu section**

The **Logo** section should be a fixed size and in a fixed position to the top left of the page.
The **Main Menu** section and the **Sub Menu** section must be on top of each other vertically. The block they occupy must then fill the rest of the space between the Logo section and the right side of the page.

The three sections together should be fixed at the top and be visible at all times.

I have attempted to locate the particle or the atom that generates the "Menu" particle in the framework but I could not find it and edit it.

Comment: Hello Ayanami. It's not clear to me what your question is about. How the logo, main menu and submenu section are related? And what kind of help you are asking overall? Have you read the [**Gantry documentation**](http://docs.gantry.org)? Are you familiar with the technologies that gantry uses? Have you installed the demo template and tried familiarize with it? Finally you have to make the question specific to a single problem, because as is it looks like too broad.

Comment: Hello FFrewin, I see my post have been edited, my question is about how to create a custom menu/header for the gantry framework. I have gone through the documentation on the gantry framework and I cannot seem to see any indication to edit the default objects available in the gantry framework.

The rest of my post was just to give some background as to what I intend to do to create a custom menu/header.

I would prefer to edit existing objects in the framework as apposed to creating new unstable objects.

Comment: Gantry5 is powerful and allows a high level of customization out of the box, without coding experience. Still it has some learning curve, in order to familiarize with its admin area and its terminology. Most likely you don't need to edit any particles. Have you tried the [layout manager](http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/configure/layout-manager)? For fixed navigation check follow this: http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/theme-development/theme-customization.

Comment: Yes, I have tried the methods described in the link to have a fixed header. I have gone through the rest of the documentation to see if I can't find the information I need. I have even used the custom css blocks and custom javascript blocks in an attempt to create my custom header. In a last effort I attempted to use the custom html block to insert my custom header, though it worked for large displays it did not work in the framework correctly for smaller displays.

Comment: I don't wanna be harsh, sorry if it sounds so, but you realize that we have spent so much time in order to give us a bit of extra info on your case - actually just to vaguely tell us that you have tried a few things that didn't work the way you expected or something. We are volunteers here and in order to give help, we need questions that are specific to a problem, give a clear description of what a user tried, what worked, what didn't etc. We can't give answers by guessing or assuming, we can't write a whole tutorial explaining a broad topic either. Please read **[help]** and  **[ask]**

Comment: In addition - think it this way: Let's say someone would be in the mood of start writing a tutorial to explain how to make the Gantry5 header as in fixed position. What chances would have, this tutorial here to be different and more helpful than the already available documentation that you have tried and failed? This just underlines the fact that questions must be clear and specific to a single problem each time, showing coding examples, the errors produced etc - this is anyway the format and the way SE sites work.

Comment: I understand, **I need help to find and edit the "Menu" particle in the gantry framework.**

Comment: Core Gantry5 particles that do not have an override on the template level can be found at: /media/gantry5/engines/nucleus/particles/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Gantry5 particles that do not have an override on the template level can be found at:

```
/media/gantry5/engines/nucleus/particles/
```

---

[**Gantry5**](http://gantry.org) is a powerful framework and allows a high level of customization out of the box, without coding experience. Still it has some learning curve, in order to familiarize with its admin area, its terminology etc.

Most likely you don't need to edit directly any particles, but if you need it, this is absolutely possible.

For arranging your layout you need to work with [**Layout Manager**](http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/configure/layout-manager)

For fixed navigation follow this tutorial: [**Theme Customization**](http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/theme-development/theme-customization).